# Spring Boot repackage: exclude artifact with dependencies

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

My application use annotation processor `querydsl`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
    <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    <classifier>hibernate</classifier>
</dependency>
```

(`querydsl-apt` generates and compile useful classes)

But I don't want querydsl-apt in my application because I don't need it.

As

```
<scope>provided</scope>
```

and

```
<optional>true</optional>
```

is ignored by `spring-boot-maven-plugin` so I defined

```
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <excludeArtifactIds>querydsl-apt</excludeArtifactIds>
```

Now `querydsl-apt` is excluded from repackaing, but:

- querydsl-codegen
- codegen
- ecj

are included in repackaged JAR because their are `querydsl-apt` dependencies.

Is there a way to exclude entire `querydsl-apt & friends`, other than very long `excludeArtifactIds`?

PS. I tried to move `querydsl-apt` to maven-compiler-plugin dependencies but It does not work well with IntelliJ

Comment: The spring-bot-maven-plugin team strictly declines that feature. They declined that enhancement several times before, as you see on these pages, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3426 or https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3602 or etc...